# Axis 1.4.1 wsdl2Java Locator classes

Tags: client, axis, wsdl2java, generated-code

I spend a good amount of time on rest services but not so much on SOAP services. So this might be a stupid question, but i am going to ask it anyway.

I am building my wsdl files with wsdl2java (axis 1.4.1). The sample code I was given has a Service Locator class in the generated client code. I am trying to figure out if I need to build this class after my client is built or if I am doing something wrong in my wsdl2java command

```
wsdl2java.bat --test-case --generate-all --unpack-classes  -uri file.wsdl -o src
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -W -a to the cmd line parameters.  I was having problems with missing classes ( still am actually ), but those parameters created most of the missing classes.  I'll update the answer when i resolve my last missing class.

Here is the axis wsdl2java reference http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html

---

Just found that also adding -w parameter fixed my last issue.